# How to speed-up a simple method (preferably without changing interfaces or data structures)?

Tags: c++, optimization, performance

I have some data structures:

- `all_unordered_m` is a big vector containing all the strings I need (all different)
- `ordered_m` is a small vector containing the indexes of a subset of the strings (all different) in the former vector
- `position_m` maps the indexes of objects from the first vector to their position in the second one.

The `string_after(index, reverse)` method returns the string referenced by ordered_m *after* `all_unordered_m[index]`.

`ordered_m` is considered circular, and is explored in natural or reverse order depending on the second parameter.

The code is something like the following:

```
struct ordered_subset {
    // [...]

    std::vector<std::string>& all_unordered_m; // size = n >> 1
    std::vector<size_t> ordered_m;             // size << n
    std::tr1::unordered_map<size_t, size_t> position_m;  

    const std::string&
    string_after(size_t index, bool reverse) const
    {
        size_t pos = position_m.find(index)->second;
        if(reverse)
            pos = (pos == 0 ? orderd_m.size() - 1 : pos - 1);
        else
            pos = (pos == ordered.size() - 1 ? 0 : pos + 1);
        return all_unordered_m[ordered_m[pos]];
    }
};
```

Given that:

- I do need all of the data-structures for other purposes;
- I cannot change them because I need to access the strings:

  - by their id in the all_unordered_m;
  - by their index inside the various ordered_m;
- I need to know the position of a string (identified by it's position in the first vector) inside ordered_m vector;
- I cannot change the string_after interface without changing most of the program.

How can I speed up the `string_after` method that is called billions of times and is eating up about 10% of the execution time?

**EDIT:**
I've tried  making `position_m` a `vector` instead of a `unordered_map` and using the following method to avoid jumps:

```
string_after(size_t index, int direction) const
{
  return all_unordered_m[ordered_m[
      (ordered_m.size()+position_m[index]+direction)%ordered_m.size()]];
}
```

The change in position_m seems to be the most effective (I'm not sure that eliminating the branches made any difference, I'm tempted to say that the code is more compact but equally efficient with that regard).

Comment: First time I've ever seen anyone putting the *m_* (*_m* in this case) to the *right* of the member variable time.

Comment: Seems like I'm not Hungarian! ;)

Comment: (btw: having the _m on the right let me focus on the variable name!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vector` lookups are blazing fast. `size()` calls and simple arithmetic are blazing fast. `map` lookups, in comparison, are as slow as a dead turtle with a block of concrete on his back. I have often seen those become a bottleneck in otherwise simple code like this.

You could try `unordered_map` from TR1 or C++0x (a drop-in hashtable replacement of `map`) instead and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: I'm really sorry, it was a mistake in the question. I'm already using `std::tr1::unordered_map<size_t, size_t>` in real code, and still the method takes lots of time: the profiler reports: `16.76% 4.29s called: 271460532`.

Comment: You *could* replace `position_m` by a `vector<int>` of the same length as `all_unordered_m`, setting the index to `-1` in case no entry in `unordered_m` exists for that string in `all_unordered_m`. Might cost you some memory, but lookups will be fast.

Comment: Thank you! The suggestion in the comment made the function disappear from the profiler output. Easy and fast. (I was worried by the waste of memory too, but looking at it carefully does not seems an issue in this context).

Answer (score 3):

Well, in such cases (a small function that is called often) every branch can be very expensive. There are two things that come to mind.

1. Could you leave out the `reverse` parameter and make it two separate methods? This only makes sense if that doesn't simply push the `if`-statement to the calling code.
2. Try the following for calculating `pos`: `pos = (pos + 1) % ordered_m.size()` (this is for the forward case). This only works if you are sure that `pos` never overflows when incrementing it.

In general, try to replace branches with arithmetic operations in such cases, this can give you substantial speedup.

Comment: What if I change the interface a bit and make reverse in {-1, +1}? Will it make a big difference?

Comment: Well, it would get rid of the `if`-statement for the direction, but I do not know how to make to module-arithmetic work when decrementing from `0` (overflow).

Comment: As strange as it might seem (2) seem to slow the code down. (I might think that nowadays compilers and processors are smart in predicting branches, and that an integer division still costs some cycles).

Comment: Well, that was my idea, I don't have any more.

Comment: I've updated the question with an implementation of your method that avoids branches in both directions. It is more compact, but does not seem to improve performaces. It's strange because I hear a lot of people saying that it should.